# How to create unique id in Spring with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am passing Json object and inside:

```
{
"phoneName": "SOME CRAZY NAME",
"phoneId": "165464646464",
"phoneNumber": "040435005"
}
```

In spring I parse it into:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String phoneName;

@NotEmpty
private String phoneId;

@NotEmpty
private String phoneNumber;
```

The Id stays null, how can I set unique Id on the server side?

Comment: The id will be set after inserting in the db

Comment: ok, thx. will try now

Comment: @Jens, thats correct. Why dont you write answer and I can accept it.

Comment: I have write it into an answer

Answer (score 1):

The id will be set after inserting in the DB and automatically set to your model.

Answer (score 1):

You have autoincrement in your data base, you can define the next line

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

if not

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```